# Is it possible to select the relationship between to nodes in a OQGRAPH query?

Tags: mysql, mariadb, oqgraph

I'm playing around with the OQGRAPH storage engine for MariaDB https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/oqgraph-storage-engine/ and I want to implement relationships between nodes.

Example data based on https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/oqgraph-examples:

Table: people_relationships

```
origid destid relationship
1      2      friend
2      3      friend
3      4      friend
4      5      father
2      6      mother
5      6      sibling
```

When querying all destid nodes for 1:

```
SELECT * FROM people_graph g
WHERE g.latch='dijkstras' AND g.origid=1;
```

I get the shortes path to each node in sequences:

```
latch       origid  destid  weight  seq linkid
dijkstras   1       NULL    4       6   5
dijkstras   1       NULL    3       5   4
dijkstras   1       NULL    2       4   6
dijkstras   1       NULL    2       3   3
dijkstras   1       NULL    1       2   2
dijkstras   1       NULL    0       1   1
```

But I also want to know, which node leads to the relationship. In other words: Which node is the origid of the relationship (named previd).

Example:

```
latch       origid  destid  weight  seq linkid  previd
dijkstras   1       NULL    4       6   5       4
dijkstras   1       NULL    3       5   4       3
dijkstras   1       NULL    2       4   6       2
dijkstras   1       NULL    2       3   3       2
dijkstras   1       NULL    1       2   2       1
dijkstras   1       NULL    0       1   1       NULL
```

So I can limit the result to a special kind of relationships:

```
SELECT * FROM people_graph g
JOIN people_relationships d ON d.destid = g.linkid AND d.origid = g.previd
WHERE g.latch='dijkstras'
AND g.origid=1
AND d.relationship='friend';
```

Which returns friends, and friends of friends, but no family members.